# How can I implement 'Convert' with the 'Case" statement to change the display for my results?

Tags: t-sql, case

I am having trouble figuring out how to use the 'Convert' function with the 'Case' statement criteria.

I need to use Case because my report numbers can either be like '202304180108' or '12301234'. If the report number is like '12301234', I would for it to display as '23-01234'.

In other queries, I use:

```sql
CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 3, 5)) AS 'CASE #'
```

But I can not figure out how I can use it in the below query:

```sql
SELECT 
    INCUNITS.INCNUM AS [Event ID],
    CASE WHEN (SELECT INCIDENT.CASEN FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCUNITS.INCNUM = INCIDENT.INCNUM) = 0 THEN INCUNITS.INCNUM
        ELSE (SELECT CASEN FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCUNITS.INCNUM = INCIDENT.INCNUM) END AS [Report Number]
```

I tried adding the convert string after 'Select', but get variations of the error
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0-' to data type int. Both Casen and Incnum columuns are int types.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    INCUNITS.INCNUM AS [Event ID],
    CASE WHEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 3, 5)) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCUNITS.INCNUM = INCIDENT.INCNUM) = 0 THEN INCUNITS.INCNUM 
        ELSE (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(INCIDENT.CASEN, 7), 3, 5)) FROM INCIDENT WHERE INCUNITS.INCNUM = INCIDENT.INCNUM)END AS [Report Number],
    OFFICER.BADGE AS [Officer Badge ID],INCUNITS.UNITID,
```

Comment: Do you require the report numbers like '202304180108' to be formatted as well?

Comment: No, the cases like '202304180108' do not need to be formatted, they are not official report in our system.